Puedo eliminar archivos de frontEnd Mentor?
Estoy haciendo un challenge de FrontEnd mentor, saben si puedo eliminar archivos HTML para que no sea tan pesado el archivo? Cuando me lo corrijan se fijaran en eso? Lei los READ ME pero no dice nada de borrar pero como soy nuevo en esto no quiero cometer errores.
